# Externally Owned Account use Contrast account to transfer ether

Tags: solidity

can I use a Externally Owned Account to call contract account function to transfer ether to other Externally Owned Accounts, and the ether is from contract account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and it's very simple to do.

Something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract MyContr {
    function transfer(address payable receiver, uint amount) public {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount);
        receiver.transfer(amount);
    }
}
```

Then you deploy the contract, get its ABI and address, input those into a wallet software of your choice and send a transaction to the `transfer` function of the contract with the required parameters.

You should of course add all sort of security checks (not everyone should be allowed to do the transfer).

Comment: Am I right to think so: If one EOA(1) call smart contract transfer function to another EOA(2), it means that it will cost smart contract account's ether instead of EOA(1).

Comment: The Ether can come from either EOA1 or from the smart contract - it's up to you to decide how it should work

Comment: yeah, but I don't know how to let the ether come from smart contract, I tried in remix, but I found I take the ether from the EOA1.

Comment: Just use the code I gave you. Of course the contract has to have some Ether to be able to send it.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen The `require` seems redundant here.

Comment: "The Ether can come from either EOA1 or from the smart contract..." To clarify, when you call `receiver.transfer(amount)`, the transferred ether _always_ comes from the contract's balance. But how the ether got into the contract in the first place is up to you.

Comment: I use these code and I use `msg.sender` instead of `amount` and I use EOA1 to call the function, and I found it cost EOA1's ether, do I need to just use `amount` rather than `msg.sender` to cost ether from contract's balance? and how can I assign value to amount , I tried 5 ether and 500 , but I found it had an error in remix " like I need to add payable to constructor, but I already added".

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have further problems - extended discussions in comments are discouraged

Comment: ok, I will open another problem, but I didn't solve these question. I hope you can help me more about how to use ether from contract.